How can I efficiently reverse a k-group of nodes in a linked list in Java without using extra space?
I'm working on a problem where I need to reverse nodes in a singly linked list in groups of k. The solution needs to be in-place, meaning I can't use extra space beyond a few variables. I've tried several approaches but am struggling to get an efficient solution that meets these requirements.
Here are the specific requirements:

Reverse nodes in k-groups.
If the number of nodes is not a multiple of k, the remaining nodes at the end should remain as they are.
The solution must be in-place.

For example, given the linked list 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 and k = 3, the output should be 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 5.
Here's a simplified version of my linked list implementation:
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}

public class ReverseKGroup {

public static ListNode reverseKGroup(ListNode head, int k) {
    // Implement the logic here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
    head.next = new ListNode(2);
    head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
    head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
    head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

    int k = 3;
    ListNode newHead = reverseKGroup(head, k);

    // Print the reversed list
    while (newHead != null) {
        System.out.print(newHead.val + " -> ");
        newHead = newHead.next;
        }
    }
}

How can I implement the reverseKGroup method to reverse the nodes in k-groups efficiently and in-place? Any detailed explanation or code example would be greatly appreciated!

If your code works, but the question is about improving it, should the question be at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour instead of here?

Algorithm:

If we have no head or no head.next, we return the head.
First, we have to count the nodes and make sure that if we have k or more nodes.
Then, we recursively call the reverseKGroup(head, k) method to reverse the group.

For reversing, we reverse the node pointers, by assigning the head.next to a temp node, head.next to curr, curr to head and finally head to the temp node, while count != 0.
The new head of reversed group is curr, therefore, head = curr.




class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}

public class ReverseKGroup {

    public static ListNode reverseKGroup(ListNode head, int k) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        ListNode curr = head;
        int count = 0;


        while (curr != null && count != k) {
            curr = curr.next;
            count++;
        }


        if (count == k) {
            curr = reverseKGroup(curr, k);


            while (count > 0) {
                ListNode temp = head.next;
                head.next = curr;
                curr = head;
                head = temp;
                count--;
            }

            head = curr; 
        }

        return head;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
        head.next = new ListNode(2);
        head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
        head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);

        int k = 3;
        ListNode newHead = reverseKGroup(head, k);

        // Print the reversed list
        while (newHead != null) {
            System.out.print(newHead.val + " -> ");
            newHead = newHead.next;
        }
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}


Prints
3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 5 -> null


This can be solved using iterative way as well. Though this requires knowing the the size of the list, which can be easily calculated. Here is a note describing the approach in short.:

Here is a sample implementation of the idea with comments in place:

class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
public class ReverseKGroup {


    public static ListNode reverseKGroup(ListNode head, int k) {
        // Implement the logic here
        // get the size of the list
        int size = getLinkedListSize(head);
        // get the total number of group
        int totalGroup = size / k;

        ListNode prevGroupLast = new ListNode(-1); // initialized to a dummy node to facilitate implementation
        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode ansNode = null; // to store the head of the K group reversed list
        for (int i = 0; i < totalGroup; i++) {
            // Store the first element of this group, this will become the last element in the reversed view
            ListNode groupFirst = head;

            for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
                ListNode next = head.next; // we need reference to the next element since head.next pointer will get updated with prev
                if (j == k) { // this means that the current group has ended, we need to modify
                    prevGroupLast.next = head;
                    prevGroupLast = groupFirst; // current group head becomes the last element
                    groupFirst.next = next; // since current group head is last element, so its next pointer should be next groups first element
                }
                // this reverses [prev -> head] to [prev <- head]
                head.next = prev;
                prev = head;
                head = next;

            }

            // if it is the first group, the last element will be the head of the final answer
            if (i == 0) {
                ansNode = prev;
            }
        }

        // If size is not divisible by k, that means a last group exists for which we just need to adjust the pointer of the previous group
        // last element to the current element head.
        if (size % k != 0) {
            prevGroupLast.next = head;
        }
        return ansNode;
    }

    private static int getLinkedListSize(ListNode head) {
        ListNode temp = head;
        int count = 0;
        while (temp != null) {
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return count;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
        head.next = new ListNode(2);
        head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
        head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5);
        head.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(6);
        head.next.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(7);
        head.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(8);

        int k = 3;
        ListNode newHead = reverseKGroup(head, k);

        // Print the reversed list
        while (newHead != null) {
            System.out.print(newHead.val + " -> ");
            newHead = newHead.next;
        }
    }
}




The output is as expected:
3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 8 -> 

